# Let $S$ denote the set of all functions $f :\{0,1\}^4 \rightarrow \{0,1\}$. What is the number of functions from the set $S$ to the set $\{0,1\}$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

They say the answer is $2^{2^{16}}$ but I think the answer is $3^{3^{16}}$ because they have not specified the functions to be total.  Am I correct?

PS: I am a newbie so please don't be too harsh if I have made some terrible mistake.

Comment: The ordinary meaning of $f:A\to B$ is that $f$ is total.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying...I was not aware...feeling a bit humiliated.

Comment: BTW:Is there any special notation for partial functions?? If the question were about all kinds of functions would I have been correct???

Answer (score 1):

**The size of $S$ is $2^{16}$, and therefore the answer to your question is indeed $2^{2^{16}}$.**

First, let's examine the set $S=\{f:[0,1]^4\rightarrow[0,1]\}$:

- The domain of each function in the set $S$ contains $16$ elements
- The range of each function in the set $S$ contains $2$ elements
- Hence we have $2^{16}$ different functions in the set $S$

Now, let's examine the set $T=\{g:S\rightarrow[0,1]\}$:

- The domain of each function in the set $T$ contains $2^{16}$ elements
- The range of each function in the set $T$ contains $2$ elements
- Hence we have $2^{2^{16}}$ different functions in the set $T$

Comment: If the question were about all kinds of functions(total and partial)then would my answer have been correct???

Comment: @user21054: I didn't say it was **your answer**, I said that the answer was indeed what's written at the beginning of your question.

Comment: @user21054: If you consider partial functions as functions, then yes, it is $3^3^{16}$.

Comment: @user21054: A function must map **every element** in the domain to **exactly one element** in the range. So the domain has to be "covered" but the range doesn't (that's simply how functions are defined; otherwise, they're not considered functions).

Comment: @barakmanos Excuse me if I'm wrong but isn't it that only *total* functions map every element in the domain?

Comment: @EulCan: As far as I know, a function must map **the entire** domain. That's what I recall from when I was in high school. Then again, it's been a long time since high school, so they might have changed the definitions during this time.

Comment: @barakmanos Lucky you; I was never taught it! But from what I can find, the definitions seem quite vague & intuitive.

Comment: @EulCan: I guess we just didn't go to the same high school :)